# Can ArcHydro tools be used on a network in an SDE enterprise geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, network, flow

Most of the documentation for ArcHydro tools discusses their use on data in ESRI's personal and file geodatabases. Is it possible to use ArcHydro tools to set network flow direction on a networked data set in an 'enterprise geodatabase' (SDE on Oracle)? Both the client and server are at version 9.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This paper](http://gis.library.esri.com/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=33982&query_desc=kw%2Cwrdl%3A%20ArcHydro) describes use of ArcHydro with ArcSDE.

Reference:

> SJRWMD Arc Hydro: GIS for Better Water Resources Management.
>   by Fox, Sandra; Bourne, Stephen; Lin, Adrian; Ceric, Aisa.
>   Publisher: San Diego, CA 2007.

<sub>edited by AndreSilva: the link on previous version of this post was broken, and the correct paper was found [here](http://gis.library.esri.com/cgi-bin/koha/opac-search.pl?q=ArcHydro&limit=%28branch%3AEDCOMMUN+or+branch%3AURISABOK+or+branch%3AGISBIBLI%29), by clicking on "view paper online" link; the url will show the same number of paper as the previous broken link, i.e., "pap_1836".</sub>

Comment: This pretty much answers my question as to whether it is possible.  I think that the issue that I was having was that the SDE database needs to be versioned to allow editing.  As far as I can tell, disconnected editing will not work with ArcHydro.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the Help documents included with the ArcHydro Tools download I did see references to SDE so I would say yes.